# TypeError: Model.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

This is my first time using sequelize with postgres. I have a `user.js` model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize")

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    sequelize.define("User", {
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
}
```

and a `user.js` controller which saves the user into the database

```
const User = require("../models/user")

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const newUser = await User.create({username: username, password: password})
    res.status(201).send("Success!")
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("error")
  }
};
```

Then in my `database.js` file:

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("myDB", process.env.USER, process.env.PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    dialect: "postgres"
});

const modelDefiners = [require("../models/user")]

for (const modelDefiner of modelDefiners){
    modelDefiner(sequelize)
}

module.exports = sequelize;
```

The problem is that when I post data and call the User.create() function I get this error `TypeError: User.create is not a function`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned because "User" is not of type sequelize model. I think you will have to return schema from model. Also if this doesn't works then check if you have ran the migration for this user model. Also check if the database is connected successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `user` object in `user.js`

```
const { DataTypes } = require ("sequelize")
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define ("User", {
    //...
  })
  return User // add this line
}
```

OR, you can call the function with sequelize instance as the argument, but this is not the standard way.

```
const User = require ("../models/user")(sequelize)
```